# R grepl - matching two strings

Tags: regex, r

I am facing problem with using grep/grepl function in R. When I run

```
grepl("[Aa][Bb][Cc]x", c("Abcx", "abCy"))
```

I got:

```
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

And it's OK. Similarly, for:

```
grepl("[Aa][Bb][Cc]y", c("Abcx", "abCy"))
```

I got:

```
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

And it's also allrighty. But when I write:

```
grepl("[Aa][Bb][Cc]x | [Aa][Bb][Cc]y", c("Abcx", "abCy"))
```

it gives me counter-intuitive

```
[1] FALSE FALSE
```

What's the problem?

Comment: ...remove the spaces on either side of the `|`?

Comment: Yeah, realized my mistake just after commenting @user22

Comment: @joran thank you! Still, I don't understand, why it takes into account blank spaces when there is \\s for typing space in regex?

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove spaces around `|`:

```
grepl("[Aa][Bb][Cc]x|[Aa][Bb][Cc]y", c("Abcx", "abCy"))
```

These spaces matter. You might use a PCRE regex though with a `(?x)` modifier (see [demo](http://ideone.com/jbAq9U)) that makes it possible to introduce some formatting whitespace in between subpatterns for better readability:

```
grepl("(?x)[Aa][Bb][Cc]x | [Aa][Bb][Cc]y", c("Abcx", "abCy"), perl=TRUE)
```

Or better use this shorter version:

```
grepl("[Aa][Bb][Cc][xy]", c("Abcx", "abCy"))
```

where the pattern is first shrunk to `[Aa][Bb][Cc](x|y)` and since these are single characters, I recommend using a character class (`(x|y)` -> `[xy]`).

Comment: Thank you! Still, I don't understand, why it takes into account blank spaces when there is \\s for typing space in regex? Or it's true but only for perl-like expressions?

Comment: Note that `\s` stands for more than just a literal space. It may match a space, a tab, a newline, Unicode whitespace. A literal space is meaningful by default, without the `(?x)` modifier available in PCRE (base R with `perl=TRUE`) and ICU (stringr/stringi packages) regex flavors.

Comment: As far as I know "\s" stands only for space (as opposed to [:space:]) -> see grepl("\\s", "\\t")

Comment: @user2280549 see `grepl("\\s", "\t")`

Comment: This [TRE reference](https://github.com/laurikari/tre/blob/master/doc/tre-syntax.html) proves `\s` = `[:space:]`. For PCRE meaning of `\s`, see [pcre.org](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) (*`\s`     any white space character*, default is *HT (9), LF (10), VT (11), FF (12), CR (13), and space (32)*, and if the PCRE_UCP  option is set, `\s` matches *any character that matches `\p{Z}` or `\h` or `\v`*).

Comment: Ok, your reference looks much more trustworthy. I'd used [this source](http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/gsub.php), thus I was a bit confused. Thank you once more

Comment: TRE `[[:space:]]` seems to match `[ \t\r\n\v\f]` (taken from http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html). Oh, that source says `\w` stands for a word - also rather misleading.

Comment: So as official R documentation [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html)

Comment: [There](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html), at the bottom, there are links to actual libraries documentation.